# QML transition changes immediately, not according to 'duration'

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, transition

I have the following QML file. I wan't the rectangle **myRect** to slide in from the right when the **root** item is clicked (simplified setup). What actually happens is that **myRect** appears immediately when the **root** item is clicked.

I checked the *running* property on the transition and that seems to be fine. It logs *true* when I click the **root** item, and then *false* after 2 seconds.

Does anyone know why the *x* property doesn't gradually change?

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item{
    id: root

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            myRect.state = "visible"
        }
    }          

    Rectangle{
        id: myRect

        width: root.width
        height: root.height

        state: "hidden"

        color: "yellow"

        states: [
            State {
                name: "hidden"
                PropertyChanges{
                    target: myRect
                    x: myRect.width
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "visible"
                PropertyChanges{
                    target: myRect
                    x: 0
                }
            }                
        ]
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                NumberAnimation{
                    duration: 2000
                }
                onRunningChanged: {
                    console.log("Running:", running)
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indicate the property, in your case "x"

```
NumberAnimation{
    duration: 2000
    properties: "x"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I actually tried that ealier, but forgot the ""